# Why is there an "unexpected mutation of prop" when this is not a prop?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

This code below triggers an error for the `<q-input>` component

```
 ESLint: Unexpected mutation of "serviceName" prop. (vue/no-mutating-props)
```

The thing I do not understand is why `serviceName` is seen as a prop when I explicitly crated the reference from the prop.

Does this mean that changes in `serviceName` will bubble to `props`? If so does this mean that I have to **copy** the contents of `props` into a new reactive variable, breaking the relationship with the prop?

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-form
    @submit="true"
    >
      <div class="row q-gutter-md">
        <q-input v-model="serviceName" label="service" class="" filled></q-input>
      </div>
      <div class="row q-gutter-md">
        <q-input v-model="serviceConf.image" label="image"></q-input>
        <q-input v-model="serviceConf.container_name" label="container_name"></q-input>
      </div>
    </q-form>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  name: 'EditService'
}
</script>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { toRef, PropType } from 'vue'
import { ServiceFull } from 'components/defs'

const props = defineProps({
  serviceName: {
    type: String
  },
  serviceConf: {
    type: Object as PropType<ServiceFull>
  }
})
const serviceName = toRef(props, 'serviceName')
const serviceConf = toRef(props, 'serviceConf') as unknown as ServiceFull

</script>
```

For reference, `ServiceFull` is defined as

```
// name of the service
export type ServiceName = string
// description of the service below the name
export interface ServiceConfig {
  container_name: string
  image: string
  environment: string[]
  restart: string
  volumes: string[]
  ports: string[]
  depends_on: string[]
  cap_add: string[]
}
// complete service, name + config → used to transfer between components
export interface ServiceFull {
  name: ServiceName
  conf: ServiceConfig
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#toref) explain that `toRef` keeps a reactive connection to the source property, so modifying the resulting `ref` would update the original property. In addition to the linter warning, you'd see a browser console warning when trying to use this `ref` in a `v-model`:

> Set operation on key "serviceName" failed: target is readonly.

To be able to modify `serviceName` independently from the prop, you could use a `ref` of the prop value (i.e., a copy):

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'
const serviceName = ref(props.serviceName)
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-use-prop-value-in-vmodel?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FEditService.vue)